# TypoScript appends '>' when rendering content from tt_content

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to upgrade TYPO3 from version 4.6 to 4.7. The extension automaketemplate (0.20) is used for the site templates.

I have the following code to retrieve some content from the tt_content table:

```
lib.darkbar < styles.content.get
lib.darkbar.select.pidInList = {$contentpage.darkbarPID}
```

For debugging the actual bodytext in the tt_content table is simply the string 'BODYTEXT'. The rendered content in 4.7 is:

```
<div id="site-darkbar-navigation">
    <!--  CONTENT ELEMENT, uid:96/text [begin] -->
        >
        <!--  Text: [begin] -->
            <p class="bodytext">BODYTEXT</p>
        <!--  Text: [end] -->
            </div>
```

In 4.6 I did not have the > sign. Where does it come from?

Comment: Did you look at the database table tt_content record id=96? Maybe there is some strange content in. But I recommend how @taunusweb described upgrade to 6.2, then 7.6 and solve then all bugs.

Comment: Yes I had a look at the raw record and it is ok. I also wrote a comment to taunusweb's answer that the same problem occurs in 6.2. After some hours of debugging it seems the problem comes from the css_styled_content extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you somewhere have declared an additional `>` in your configuration. this might come from PHP, typoscript or fluid-/marker-template.
you might search for something like `>>` in your sources (like `<br />>`)

Another possibility (especially after a version change [1]): the rendering of some wraps is done 'unbalanced' (= opening and closing are done in the same TEXT or wrap). there might be a wrap as COA something like:

```
...wrap.cObject = COA
...wrpa.cObject {
   10 = TEXT
   10.value = <div class="default

   20 = TEXT
   20.value = variant
   20.if.equals.field = layout
   20.if.value = 1

   30 = TEXT
   30.value = ">|</div>
}
```

(here the opening and closing is done in the same wrap, but the wrap consists of three TEXTs and the opening is done in 10 and clsing in 30)

While in an earlier version all was done in 10, we now have three parts. If you removed the wrap in the early version just with `...10 >` it now leaves an broken HTML-Tag.

You might deactivate one part of your configuration after the other until you can localize the error. (Extensions, Templates, Typoscript)

[1] the rendering of contentelements was always topic of changes to reflect state of the art HTML markup. As the rendering was done primary in typoscript and the static template of CSC each version of TYPO3 had compatibility versions of CSC. In your case you might use the static template compatible to the version of the first build so that modifications to the rendering match the rendering.

Comment: I already could it pin down to the css_styled_content extension. There is some TypoScript `tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.30.value = >|</div>` that seems to be the problem. I just could not figure out why this is a problem in 4.7 and not in 4.6. This is probably also the cause for the broken indentation.

Comment: I would assume you have configured a modification of the default rendering of CSC. with the version-change the rendering of CSC changed and the formerly clean rendering gets corrupted. propably with 4.7 in `tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.10` the div-Tag should be opened, in `.20` there were some classes appended and all is closed in `.30`. maybe in 4.6 all was handled in `.10` and you removed it in an configuration. and so the wrapping with a div tag was removed in 4.6 it was unbalanced broken in 4.7

Comment: Hi Bernd! After some further debugging I already came to the same conclusion. But I am currently at an expo and hat no time yet to write a detailed answer. If you want you can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I modified my answer to include unbalanced wraps.